# upper limit of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I read it somewhere that the upper limit of the a bounded sequence, let say ${\{a_n}\}$ is defined as 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup a_n \ := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \{ a_k \mid k \geq n \} ,
$$
However, I feel like I am not entirely convinced by this definition. Let say${\{a_n}\}= {1,0,0,0,0,...}$ then wouldn't $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \{ a_k \mid k \geq n \}$ be 0 rather than 1 in this case? 
(I feel like this definition only works on non-decreasing sequence, no? Also I am quite bad at analysis so apologise in advance if this is something entirely obvious.

Comment: $\limsup$ is not the same thing as $\sup$. So yes, for the sequence $1, 0, 0, 0...$, the $\limsup$ is $0$ and not $1$.

Comment: ohh i get it now, sorry I thought them as the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Yes. And $\limsup_na_n=0$. So, there is no contradiction.

And, yes, it is true, in general, that, if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence,$$\limsup_na_n=\lim_n\sup\{a_k\,|\,k\geqslant n\}.$$

Comment: Hello!! Why does this equality hold? Could you give me a hint how we prove that?

Comment: @MaryStar How do you defined $\limsup_na_n$?

Comment: It is the greatest limit of $a_n$

Comment: Then let $S=\limsup_na_n$. If $M>S$, then there are only finitely many $k$'s such that $a_k>\frac{M+S}2$; otherwise, since the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded, it would have a subsequence convergent to some limit $l\geqslant\frac{M+S}2>S$, which is impossible, by the definition of $S$. So, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n\leqslant\frac{M+S}2$ if $n\geqslant N$. Then $n\geqslant N\implies\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\leqslant\frac{M+S}2$, and therefore $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\leqslant\frac{M+S}2<M$. This proves that $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\leqslant S$.

Comment: On the othr hand, there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ which converges to $S$. Then, for any number $N<S$, you have $a_{n_k}>N$ if $k$ is large enough, and so$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}>N,$$which implies that $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}>N$. So, $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\geqslant S$.

Comment: Ahh!!! It is very clear now!!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: Ithought again about that proof... How do we get from $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\leqslant\frac{M+S}2<M$ the inequality $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\leqslant S$ ?

Comment: And at the other direction... How do we get from $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}>N$ that $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}\geqslant S$ since $N<S$ ?

Comment: If $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}>S$, then let $M=\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}$. We have $M>S$ and I proved that then $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}<M$. In other words, $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}<\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}$. There's a contradiction here.

Comment: So $M$ is an arbitrary number greater than $S$ and we take it equal to $\lim_n\sup\{a_k\mid k\geqslant n\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did to get a contradiction.

Comment: Ahh!! I see!! Thanks for the clarification!! :-)